# Rad Menu XML NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am getting this Exception:

```
System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace) 
   System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader) +107.......
```

I get this exception sometimes by pressing a button on a page that has a master page containing a menu.

Here is my master page code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session["MenuXML"] != null)
            xmlDataSource.Data = Session["MenuXML"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

xmlDataSource is a menu in an aspx file telerik:RadMenu.

Here is my XML which is a string format and is stored in session:

```
<Menus>
  <Menu>
    <MenuID>3</MenuID>
    <Text>    Book</Text>
    <Navigate>#</Navigate>
    <Menu>
      <MenuID>51</MenuID>
      <Text>  Hotel Search</Text>
      <Navigate>Search.aspx</Navigate>
      <ParentID>3</ParentID>
    </Menu>
  <Menu>
    this tag repeating itself......
  </Menu>
</Menus>
```

Comment: Please check below link. It will help you to resolved this issue. IF you are not able to resolved this issue then please provide your xml file data. http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/menu/examples/programming/xmldefinition/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: I have included my xml in it please review it